# Expose Hudson system info to remote API

Tags: java, xml, api, hudson, jenkins

I was wondering if anyone has been able to expose the system info from Hudson/Jenkins to the remote API?

I manage multiple instances and would like to be able to gather some basic information and statistics about each instance together to be able to compare them.

At the moment, I would just like to obtain the java.home directory so I can resolve the version of Java being used on builds that show "(Default)" as the jdkVersion. But would also like some load statistics/memory usage is possible.

Comment: see question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348184/how-can-i-get-system-configuration-for-jenkins-using-remote-access-api/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find this information in the Jenkins wiki https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

Comment: I have already used this, but it doesnt expose system variables, I was hoping someone may have alreay produced a plugin/found another way to access this information

Comment: Well, you can always locate the settings files of jenkins, parse them and gather the data you want. The shell script for this would not be complicated.