# How to get a list of all available jenkins APIs

Tags: jenkins

For restart:

```
     <Jenkins server>/restart
```

To Trigger a build (POST call)

```
   <Jenkins server>/job/<job-name>/build
```

Is there a way to see the list of all such Jenkins APIs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find jenkins restful api reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661362/where-can-i-find-jenkins-restful-api-reference)